# Multiprocessing / How to map a function with 2 arg comprised in a comprehensive list of tuple

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my need:

I have a huge set of IPs to test within a complicated network. For better understanding, IP is associated with the name of the equipment. Test shouldn't last too long, so multiprocess seems to be a good idea.

```
poolThread = Pool(threadNumber)
results = poolThread.map(testIP, [tupleIP for tupleIP in listTupleIP])

def testIP(name, ip): [...]
```

But I'm stucked at unpacking the tupleIP when I'm mapping to the function.
I've tried to do [tupleIP[0], tupleIP[1]]... well this is a list not two different arguments.

The easy way is to unpack in the function and it works perfectly. Nevertheless, I'd like to know if there is an elegant way to do this otherwise.

Comment: `def testIP(name, ip):` ... should probably be just with one argument

Comment: Correct, it works with one argument but I want to avoid having the function with a knowledge of extern object. In this case this function needs to unpack two arguments from a tuple.

Comment: Maybe it should be something like `def testIP(addr): name, ip = addr`. The first argument for `map()` like functions is generally a function that accepts one argument, and is called with one argument.